# Why the change of the scrum verbal directions to "Crouch-Touch-Set"?

Tags: terminology, rugby-union

Since I've watched Rugby in the late 90's, the referee's verbal directions for the scrum have been either:

> Crouch-Pause-Engage

or for the last several years:

> Crouch-Touch-Pause-Engage

I was watching the [Six Nations](http://www.rbs6nations.com/) games today, and the directions have changed to:

> Crouch-Touch-Set

Unfortunately I live in a country where Rugby is not really watched.  Can someone explain to me why the directions have changed, and what the thinking is?

Comment: The Rugby Championship (Australia/New Zealand/South Africa/Argentina) just finished and they used a different set of commands again: crouch-bind-set. The players would bind together but not allowed to push until set. Seemed to keep the scrum from collapsing a bit better in the games I saw

Comment: @Greg - that sounds completely sensible, and kind of like the way that Rugby League scrums are set, but hopefully a bit more of the competition of a Union scrum.  I wonder whether the Six Nations will use it.

Comment: It was some of the best scrums I've seen in a while. Instead of being about the initial engagement it was about the ongoing pressure you could apply through the scrum. Also allowed the ref to make sure the ball was feed into the middle of the scrum

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Law 20 of the International Rugby Board states the laws regarding the scrum, and [20.1 specifies the forming of the scrum](http://www.irblaws.com/index.php?highlight=scrum&law=20.1). [Amendment 21](http://www.irblaws.com/index.php?domain=11&amendment=21) to this section states the following:

> CURRENT LAW
>   20.1 Forming a scrum
>
> (g)
>
> The referee will call “crouch” then “touch”. The front rows crouch
>   and, using their outside arm, each prop touches the point of the
>   opposing props outside shoulder. The props then withdraw their arms.
>   The referee will then call “pause”. Following a pause the referee will
>   then call “engage”. The front rows may then engage. The “engage” call
>   is not a command but an indication that the front rows may come
>   together when ready.
>
> AMENDED LAW
>   20.1 Forming a scrum
>
> (g)
>
> The referee will call “crouch” then “touch”. The front rows crouch
>   and, using their outside arm, each prop touches the point of the
>   opposing prop’s outside shoulder. The props then withdraw their arms.
>   Following a pause the referee will then call “set” when the front rows
>   are ready. The front rows may then engage. The “set” call is not a
>   command but an indication that the front rows may come together when
>   ready.

While the official page for the amendment does not have any information as to why this change was made, the [wikipedia article on scrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28rugby%29) claims that the change was to speed up the scrum:

> "Pause" has been removed in order to speed up the scrum and to
>   minimize resets due to collapsed scrums.

I found [another article](http://www.theaustralian.com.au/news/wallabies-prop-benn-robinson-backs-irb-trial-which-will-see-pause-call-removed-from-scrum-sequence/story-fncagcd8-1226358559082) on "The Australian" which claims that the change in directions during scrum is one of the changes on trial basis for 2013, and that 
the motivation was to decrease the risk of injuries as well as speeding up the game. The article features opinions from several professionals as well, good read.

Answer (score 4):

The reason set replaces engage is because engage is a very awkward word to use. It has two syllables, and worse, the stressed syllable is the second one. The effect is like saying "ready, set,  g-Go" in a running race. Because scrummaging is time critical to a matter of milliseconds, a single syllable word is much more efficient.

Comment: This is a very good point. I had not considered that, particularly in pro games where as you say milliseconds count.

Comment: Additionally the teams used to go on the 1st syllable of the engage meaning that there was a potential timing issue.  So by bringing it to a single syllable its easier.   The words matter less as senior players tend to go on the 3rd sound from the referee rather than what it is.  Hence when standing a scrum up you always blow your whistle

Answer (score 2):

Before 2013 the sequence was "crouch, touch, pause, engage". Typically that meant each team's pack would form up about a foot apart and hold back until the the referee said "engage", at which point the two packs would smash into each other. In the professional game the impact at "engage" kept getting bigger and bigger - the talk was of winning "the hit" - and it resulted in a lot of collapsed scrums and injuries.

Since 2013 the sequence has been "crouch, bind, set". The two front rows bind together before the scrum starts and the two packs start pushing against each other. The point is to reduce the impact by eliminating "the hit", making the scrum safer and more stable.